# Creating functions with Array as parameter not work with me

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

In short, I have a function like the following:

```
function plus($x, $y){
   echo $x+$y;
}
```

I want to tell the function its parameters as array like the following:

```
$parms = array(20,10);
plus($parms);
```

But unfortunately, not work.
I'm tired by using another way as the following:

```
$parms = array(20,10);
$func_params = implode(',', $parms);
plus($func_params);
```

And also not work, and gives me Error message:
`Warning: Missing argument 2 for plus(), called in.....`

And now, I'm at a puzzled.
What can I do to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple things you can do. 
Firstly, to maintain your function definition you can use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). I think this is ugly.

```
call_user_func_array('plus', $parms);
```

You can make your function more robust by taking a variable number of params:

```
function plus(){
  $args = func_get_args();
  return $args[0] + $args[1];
}
```

You can simply accept an array and add everything up:

```
function plus($args){
  return $args[0] + $args[1];
}
```

Or you could sum up all arguments:

```
function plus($args){
  return array_sum($args);
}
```

This is PHP, there are 10 ways to do everything.

Comment: Thanks, the first way is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt your function so that it only accepts one parameter and then in the function itself, you can process that parameter:

Very simple example:

```
function plus($arr){
   echo $arr[0]+$arr[1];
}

$parms = array(20,10);
plus($parms);
```

You can easily adapt that to loop through all elements, check the input, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Heh? The error message is *very* clear: you ask for *two* parameters in your function, but you only provide one.

If you want to pass an array, it would be a single variable.

```
function plus($array){
    echo ($array[0]+$array[1]);
}
$test = array(1,5);
plus($test); //echoes 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function plus($arr){
   $c = $arr[0]+$arr[1];
   echo $c;
}
```

And the you can invoke:

```
$parms = array(20,10);
plus($parms);
```